# How do I calculate acceleration/deceleration in the direction of travel from X,Y,Z accelerometer readings from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, algorithm, accelerometer

I am writing an iPhone/iPad app. I need to compute the acceleration and deceleration in the direction of travel of a vehicle traveling in close to a straight horizontal line with erratic acceleration and deceleration. I have the sequence of 3 readings from the X,Y,Z orthogonal accelerometers. But the orientation of the iphone/ipad is arbitrary and the accelerometer readings include vehicle motion and the effect of gravity. The result should be a sequence of single acceleration values which are positive or negative depending on whether the vehicle is decelerating or accelerating. The positive and negative direction is arbitrary so long as acceleration has the opposite sign to deceleration. Gravity should be factored out of the result. Some amount of variable smoothing of the result would be useful.

The solution should be as simple as possible and must be computationally efficient. The answer should be some kind of pseudo-code algorithm, C code or a sequence of equations which could easily be converted to C code. An iPhone specific solution in Objective C would be fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is really tough to separate gravity and motion. It's easier if you can analyze the data together with a gyroscope and compass signal.

The gyroscope measures the rate of angular rotation.  Its integral is theoretically the angular orientation (plus an unknown constant), but the integral is subject to drift, so is useless on its own.  The accelerometer measures angular orientation plus gravity plus linear acceleration.  With some moderately complex math, you can isolate all 3 of those quantities from the 2 sensors' values.  Adding the compass fixes the XY plane (where Z is gravity) to an absolute coordinate frame.

See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) great presentation.

Answer (score 3):

You will need some trigonometry for this, for example to get the magnitude you need

```
magn = sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
```

to get the angle you will need atan, then c function atan2 is better

```
xyangel = atan2(y,x);
xymagn = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
vertangle = atan2(z,xymagn)
```

no how you get negative and positive magnitude is arbitrary, you could for example interpret  π/2 < xyangle < 3π/2 as negative. That would be taking the sign of x for the sign of magn, but it would be equally valid to take the sign from y

Comment: wat is the unit for magnitude in iphone? shall we use Acceleration Magnitude (Calculated):
(√(Accelx2+Accely2+Accelz2))/ 9.80665

Answer (score 2):

Use [userAcceleration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/userAcceleration).

You don't have to figure out how to remove gravity from the accelerometer readings and how to take into accont the orientation: **It is already implemeted** in the Core Motion Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Track the mean value of acceleration. That will give you a reference for "down". Then subtract the mean from individual readings.

You'll need to play around with the sensitivity of the mean calculation, since, e.g., making a long slow turn on a freeway will cause the mean to slowly drift outwards.

If you wanted to compensate for this, you could use GPS tracking to compute a coarse-grained global acceleration to calibrate the accelerometer. In fact, you might find that differentiating the GPS velocity reading gives a good enough absolute acceleration all by itself (I haven't tried, so I can't say).