# Measure the acceleration not the angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, accelerometer

I want to measure the acceleration of the iPhone in the direction of the z-axis.
However, the code I use measures the inclination, so the angle in which the
device is located.
But I want to measure the acceleration when the iPhone for example is lifted. Like some seismograph apps.

My code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    myMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    myMotionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1;
    
    if ([myMotionManager isAccelerometerAvailable])
    {
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        
        [myMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                
                Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",accelerometerData.acceleration.z];
             
            });
        }];
        
    } else 
        NSLog(@"not active");

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: It's a physics/math issue. You have to think: What's really an acceleration? That's nothing to do with XCode by the way.

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157731/calculate-acceleration-driving-a-car and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539141/how-do-i-calculate-acceleration-deceleration-in-the-direction-of-travel-from-x-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer. I have to use userAcceleration